# Converting C# Encrypter/Decrypter to PHP

Tags: c#, php, encryption, mcrypt

I have this C# code here and I'm trying to port it to PHP. This code encrypts and decrypts text with a certain IV and Key. I'm trying to convert it to PHP but I don't understand the C# byte array IV it has. Here is the IV and then the Key.

```
private static readonly byte[] IV = new byte[32]
{
  (byte) 143,
  (byte) 18,
  (byte) 207,
  (byte) 184,
  (byte) 193,
  (byte) 173,
  (byte) 252,
  (byte) 103,
  (byte) 12,
  (byte) 202,
  (byte) 6,
  (byte) 9,
  (byte) 162,
  (byte) 187,
  (byte) 221,
  (byte) 66,
  (byte) 81,
  (byte) 192,
  (byte) 51,
  (byte) 186,
  (byte) 197,
  (byte) 251,
  (byte) 90,
  (byte) 247,
  (byte) 111,
  (byte) 237,
  (byte) 182,
  (byte) 168,
  (byte) 195,
  (byte) 0,
  (byte) 156,
  (byte) 133
};
private static readonly byte[] Key = new byte[32]
{
  (byte) 130,
  (byte) 94,
  (byte) 5,
  (byte) 131,
  (byte) 159,
  (byte) 45,
  (byte) 165,
  (byte) 206,
  (byte) 66,
  (byte) 115,
  (byte) 19,
  (byte) 144,
  (byte) 242,
  (byte) 142,
  (byte) 97,
  (byte) 6,
  (byte) 50,
  (byte) 47,
  (byte) 92,
  (byte) 70,
  (byte) 241,
  (byte) 179,
  (byte) 77,
  (byte) 121,
  (byte) 222,
  (byte) 243,
  (byte) 13,
  (byte) 171,
  (byte) 16,
  (byte) 92,
  (byte) 197,
  (byte) 174
};
```

I tried converting that to a string but I get a lot of weird characters. In PHP, I'm hoping to be able to do this:
`base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, "KEY_HERE", $text, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, "IV HERE", MCRYPT_RAND)))`

Here are the C# Encrypt and Decrypt functions:

```
private string EncryptCommand(string command)
{
  using (Rijndael rijndael = (Rijndael) new RijndaelManaged())
  {
    rijndael.KeySize = 256;
    rijndael.BlockSize = 256;
    rijndael.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
      using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream((Stream) memoryStream, rijndael.CreateEncryptor(API.Key, API.IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
      {
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(command);
        cryptoStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
        return Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.ToArray());
      }
    }
  }
}

private byte[] DecryptCommand(byte[] command)
{
  using (RijndaelManaged rijndaelManaged = new RijndaelManaged())
  {
    rijndaelManaged.KeySize = 256;
    rijndaelManaged.BlockSize = 256;
    rijndaelManaged.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
      using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream((Stream) memoryStream, rijndaelManaged.CreateDecryptor(API.Key, API.IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
      {
        cryptoStream.Write(command, 0, command.Length);
        cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
        return memoryStream.ToArray();
      }
    }
  }
}
}
```

The main part I'm having issues with is converting the IV and Key to strings that I can put into the PHP function. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: we are not an language translation service

Comment: Wow, thanks for that advice! But if you read my question, you would know I'm asking for help on converting the Key and IV to a string because whenever I tried I failed. Try again, maybe? ;)

Comment: Hey radu, can you post some plaintext and the resulting ciphertext from that EncryptCommand C# code? Thanks.

Comment: Plain: "test" ::::
Encrypted: "WpvppvbH0JR+9QvXrS+Fxx478Y8rg3Cu/ZMUee+vcng=" (w/o quotes)

Comment: Not sure how this is too broad, the user wants to know if byte arrays (like those in C#) exist in PHP. Seemed simple and specific enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent of a byte array is a string in PHP.

```
$iv  = array(143,18,207,184,193,173,252,103,12,202,6,9,162,187,221,66,81,192,51,186,197,251,90,247,111,237,182,168,195,0,156,133);
$key = array(130,94,5,131,159,45,165,206,66,115,19,144,242,142,97,6,50,47,92,70,241,179,77,121,222,243,13,171,16,92,197,174);

$str_iv  = implode(array_map("chr", $iv));
$str_key = implode(array_map("chr", $key));
```

So all I've done is take your byte array and convert each array value to an ASCII character and concatenate them all to a string.

I have confirmed that `$str_iv` is equal to `Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Key, 0, Key.Length)`.